# Spring MVC + thymeleaf: How to allow empty input?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**How can I allow empty input to field with type long in Spring MVC + thymeleaf?**

I want this field to take default value.
Currently I have the error:

> Field error in object 'greeting' on field 'id': rejected value [];
>   codes
>   [typeMismatch.greeting.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.long,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [greeting.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id]]; default
>   message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String'
>   to required type 'long' for property 'id'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""]]

when I try to submit form with empty id field

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head> 
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My POJO:

```
public class Greeting {

    private long id;
    private String content;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your input type of id field is text. Try changing from type="text" to type="number".

Comment: May be you can try changing id type to Long.  private Long id;  If you want to pass empty.  It will be converted to null.

Comment: Use a `Long` instead of a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact problem, fixed it using wrapper objects (Integer instead of int, Double instead of double, etc) in the POJO model classes.

Thanks Metroids for answer.